# CSS Media Query Not Overriding

Tags: html, css, overriding, media-queries

I cant quiet solve this issue. I'm still pretty new to html and css but have used media queries before, but this time although it worked for one element (sub-header), it didn't work for the other (header).

```
/* =============Standards for Texts============== */
.sub-header {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: hsl(229, 6%, 66%);
    margin-top: 6ch;
}

.header {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: hsl(234, 12%, 34%);
}

.description {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: hsl(229, 6%, 66%);
}

body > .sub-header, header {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* ===============Port to Desktop=============== */
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }


    body > .sub-header, header {
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: red;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlg2R.png)

Comment: Please include the HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a period before `header` in your CSS.

```
/* This targets a <header> tag */
header { }

/* This targets any element with a class named header */
.header { }
```

Comment: No problem, please mark as the correct answer if it helped

Comment: Yes, it will allow me to in a few minutes :)

Comment: @Blue you could actually use the header tag - it's very fancy and shiny and new :)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to put dot before header: .header inside your media query